# Google Mobile Ads and Kindle Fire

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I recently replaced AdMob library with Google Mobile Ads and I have a question about that: Will ads appear on Amazon Kindle Fire devices?

I ask this because I know that Google Mobile Ads depends on Google Play Services, so I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Google Play Services still supports devices that don't have the Google Play store
>   installed on it. The only difference is that devices without the Play
>   Store (and the accompanied Google Play Services app) on it will not receive automatic
>   updates, so you'll still want to grab new versions of the library
>   provided in Android SDK manager and include them when releasing your
>   app.

As you can see above, if Google Play Services is not installed on the device, it will fall back to the version you included with your app as a library.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/obflEHgq_og

Comment: If that is the case, why do we need to verify the Google Play Services APK is installed, as instructed [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure)?

Isn't it enough to just add their library to my app?

Comment: I assume that they prefer to use the device's version above the library. It puts them in control with bugfixes etc. and perhaps more features or more efficient.

Comment: Is that answer also related to Ads-Lite today? does Ads-Lite work on Amazon devices?