# Accessing Google Play Games out of Google Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have developed a game using Unity and I have used Google Play Games in it. It works good for testers and also for public users when I publish it on Google Play Games. The problem is I want to publish it on a local app store (and not Google Play Games) and it does not work this way! Is there any trick about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It does even work if you sell your app through google play and on another platform. But the device needs to have the google play games app installed, so it does not work on Amazon devices.

Let’s assume your app is called “TheGame”.

**Go to the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) to “All application”**:

1. Add another app name call it “TheGame (DRM-free)”
2. Create an empty APK that signed with a keystore and a different bundle identifier (if you already sell it on Google Play)
3. Upload the APK to alpha or beta testing, but not production.
4. Complete the Store Listing and Content Rating
5. Set pricing to free
6. Publish your app. (no worries it will not appear on Google Play)

**Then go [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) to "Game Services:**

1. If you not already have that add new game
2. Link your app “TheGame (DRM-free)” to you game services under “linked apps”
3. Make sure you set the “Enable anti-piracy” option to “OFF”
4. Publish your changes

This work with achievement, leaderboards and multiplayer.
The users don’t need to be testers anymore.
Also multiplayer between your DRM-free and your Google Play app is possible.

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem was "Anti-piracy" field!!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this document- [Alternative Distribution Options](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/open-distribution.html)

> As an open platform, Android offers choice. You can distribute your Android apps to users in any way you want, using any distribution approach or combination of approaches that meets your needs. From publishing in an app marketplace to serving your apps from a web site or emailing them directly users, you’re never locked into any particular distribution platform.

- Distributing Through an App Marketplace
- Distributing Your Apps by Email
- Distributing Through a Website
- User Opt-In for Apps from Unknown Sources

> Android protects users from inadvertent download and install of apps from locations other than Google Play (which is trusted). It blocks such installs until the user opts-in Unknown sources in Settings > Security, shown in image below. Users need to make this configuration change before they download your apps to their devices.

[image]

Users must enable the Unknown sources setting before they can install apps not downloaded from Google Play.

*Note that some network providers don’t allow users to install applications from unknown sources.*

Also you can check this SO question about : [What is the fall back plan for devices without Google Play Services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23678388/5995040), this may add information to ensure your app should run.

Hope it helps!